# python pandas: using pd.IndexSlice for both rows and columns in a double multiindex dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, slice, multi-index

I have a double Multiindex dataframe as follows. I slice the rows with idx = pd.IndexSlice but I dont know how to do the same with the columns
so provided this data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(9, 5))))
# rows
list1 = ['2021-01-01','2022-02-01','2022-03-01']
list2 = ['PHOTO', 'QUE','TXR']
combinations = [(x, y) for x in list1 for y in list2]     
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(combinations, names = ["DATE","DB"])
df.index.set_names(["DATE","DB"], inplace=True)
#columns
list1c = [('AB30','ACTIVE','A2'),('CD55','ACTIVE','A1'),('ZT52','UNACTIVE','A2'),('MIKE','PENSIONER','A2'),('ZZ00001','ACTIVE','A1')]
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(list1c, names = ["UserID","KIND","DEPARTMENT"])
```

I slice the rows as follows:

```
# filtering in rows
idx = pd.IndexSlice

###### ROWS #######
# slicing dates
date_start = '2021-01-01'
date_end   = '2021-02-01'
# slicing databases
databases = ['PHOTO','QUE']

# creating the index sclice for rows
i_s = idx[date_start:date_end, databases]

###### COLUMNS ######
# ??? here mask for the columns i_c = ???

df.loc[i_s, ]
```

My goal is to use the same method to slice the columns
So how I generate the IndexSlice for columns that give me for example:

pseudocode:
KIND= ACTIVE
DEPARTMENT = A2

I would like to use the same approach, for each multilevel defining a mask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
i_c = idx[: , 'ACTIVE', 'A2']

df.loc[i_s, i_c]
```

Output:

```
UserID             AB30
KIND             ACTIVE
DEPARTMENT           A2
DATE       DB          
2021-01-01 PHOTO      5
           QUE        9
```

ACTIVE or PENSIONER

```
i_c = idx[: , ['ACTIVE', 'PENSIONER'], 'A2']

df.loc[i_s, i_c]
```

Output:

```
UserID             AB30      MIKE
KIND             ACTIVE PENSIONER
DEPARTMENT           A2        A2
DATE       DB                    
2021-01-01 PHOTO      5         3
           QUE        9         2
```

Comment: What if I would like "ACTIVE" OR "PENSIONER"? Can you add that to the code?

Comment: @JFerro sure, just use a list, see update